# How to join two customer lists into one list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes:
1. a `customer` class, which contains the id and name of the customer
2. a `customer_details` class, which contain the address of the customer and so on

```
class customer
{
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    //and so on
}
class customer_details
{
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    //and so on
}
```

My question is, how can I join a `List<customer>` and a `List<customer_details>` to a single list, so it shows me the `customer_id`, `name` and `address` in a single list...

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the Join Method

Here is an example with your classes

```
 List<customer> customers = new List<customer>();
 List<customer_details> details = new List<customer_details>();

 var query = (from c in customers
                join d in details on c.customer_id equals d.customer_id
                select new
                {
                    c.customer_id,
                    c.name,
                    d.address,
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is the example using Fluent syntax, which is rather compact and preferred:

```
customers.Join(
               details,
               c=>c.customer_id,
               d=>d.customer_id,
               (c,d)=>new {c.customer_id, c.name, d.address}
              ).ToList()
```